# Alternate animated endings in a flash quiz game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to create alternate endings based on a user's score in my flash game. For some reason it will only play the alternate ending on frame 17, and never plays the one on frame 59.

```
back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,gotoFinalScreen);
function gotoFinalScreen (e:MouseEvent)
{   
    if (score>=2){
        gotoAndPlay(17);
    }
    else if (score<=3){
        gotoAndPlay(59);
    }
}
```

My animations are on two separate layers "cat" and "start/end"

[image]

Comment: Is it because your score is always more than 1? If you replace the content of `gotoFinalScreen` with just `gotoAndPlay(59);', does your problem still occur?

Comment: Did you know that your second condition ( `score<=3` ) is true for only two values which are 0 and 1 ?! What are the two intervals of scores that you want to create ?

Comment: Show you increment score.   Trace the value of score at the start of gotoFinalScreen and see if the value is what you're expecting.  `trace("Score: ",score);`